# Black screen using Flash Player in a Colorbox in IE8

Tags: jquery, flash, internet-explorer, video, colorbox

I have a problem using a random Flash video player (I can't have the name cause it's a one I get from a former website). 
When I open it on Chrome, FF or IE9+ it works well but when I try with IE8 or IE7, I get a black screen without any controls, I can't do anything.

When I open the video in a new tab (so without colorbox) it works well with IE8 and IE7

I tried to inspect the DOM on IE and I found that the #cboxLoadedContent node was absent, which explain a little.

Did you already encountered this problem or do you know a free for commercial use player which works well with colorbox in IE8 ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successed to obtain a good render on IE8 with [GDD FLV Player](http://www.gdd.ro/free-flash-flv-player)